# C# - Compare 2 lists with custom elements

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, iterator

I have 2 lists. One contains search element, one contains the data.
I need to loop for each element in list2 which contains any string in list1 ("cat" or "dog"). For examples:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add("Cat");
list1.Add("Dog");
list1.Add... ~1000 items;

List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
list2.Add("Gray Cat");
list2.Add("Black Cat");
list2.Add("Green Duck");
list2.Add("White Horse");
list2.Add("Yellow Dog Tasmania");
list2.Add("White Horse");
list2.Add... ~million items;
```

My expect is `listResult: {"Gray Cat", "Black Cat", "Yellow Dog Tasmania"}` (because it contains "cat" and "dog" in list1). Instead of nested looping, do you have any idea to make the sequence run faster?

My current solution as below. But...it seems too slow:

```
foreach (string str1 in list1)
{
   foreach (string str2 in list2)
   {
      if str2.Contains(str1)
      {
         listResult.Add(str2);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: your problem is that foreach element of list 1 you are doing a full scan of   list2 (so approx 1000 * 1M item)

Comment: Does it need to contain the _word_ or just the substring? Can list1 contain spaces as well?

Comment: In my example, I use single words "cat" and "dog", but in real case, it can be "sea lion", "killer whale"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An excellent use case for parallelization!

Linq approach without parallelization (equals internally your approach beside the fact that the internal loop breaks if one match was found - your approach also searches for other matches)

```
List<string> listResult = list2.Where(x => list1.Any(x.Contains)).ToList();
```

Parallelized the loop with `AsParallel()` - if you have a multicore system there will be a huge performance improvement.

```
List<string> listResult = list2.AsParallel().Where(x => list1.Any(x.Contains)).ToList();
```

*Runtime comparison*:
(4 core system, list1 1000 items, list2 1.000.000 items)

```
Without AsParallel(): 91 seconds
With    AsParallel(): 23 seconds
```

---

The other way with `Parallel.ForEach` and a thread safe result list

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<string> listResult = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<string>();
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<string>(list2, str2 =>
{
    foreach (string str1 in list1)
    {
        if (str2.Contains(str1))
        {
            listResult.Add(str2);
            //break the loop if one match was found to avoid duplicates and improve performance
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

---

*Side note:* You have to iterate over list2 first and `break;` after match, otherwise you add items twice: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VxoRUW

Comment: It's faster because it doesn't need the full loop of `list1` and also fixes the bug that OP is adding the same element multiple times if there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

The List string is not a suitable data structure for solving this problem efficiently.

What you are looking for is a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [Dawg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton), to sort every word from your original dictionary list1.

The aim is for every letter of word from list2, you will only have 0-26 check.

With this datastructure instead of reading a big list of word till you find one, you will be looking for word like in a paper dictionary. And that should be faster. Application that look for all word from a language in a text use this principle.

Answer (score 1):

Contains will use a 'naive approach' to string searching. You can improve on that by looking into [string search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

One way to do this could be to create a generalized [Suffix tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-set-8-suffix-tree-introduction/) for all your search words. Then iterate through all the items in your list2 to see if they match.

Still, this might be overkill. You can first try with some simple optimizations as proposed by fubo to see if that's fast enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you want to match entire words, you can use a `HashSet` to do a more efficient search and prevent iterating `list1` and `list2` more than once.

```
HashSet<string> species =
    new HashSet<string>(list1);

List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (string animal in list2)
{
    if (animal.Split(' ').Any(species.Contains))
        result.Add(animal);
}
```

If I run this (with `list1` containing 1000 items and `list2` containing 100,000 items) on a 4 core laptop:

```
The algorithm in the question:    37    seconds
The algorithm using AsParallel:    7    seconds
This algorithm:                    0.17 seconds
```

With 1 million items in `list2` this algorithm takes about a second.

---

Now while this approach does work, it might produce incorrect results. If `list1` contains **Lion** then a **Sea lion** in `list2` will be added to the results even if there is none in `list1`. (If you use a case insensitive `StringComparer` in the `HashSet` as suggested below.)

To solve that problem, you would need some way to parse the strings in `list2` into a more complex object `Animal`. If you can control your input, that may be a trivial task, but in general it is hard. If you have some way of doing that, you can use a solution like the following:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}
```

And then search the species in a `HashSet`.

```
HashSet<string> species = new HashSet<string>
{
    "Cat",
    "Dog",
    // etc.
};

List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>
{
    new Animal {Color = "Gray", Species = "Cat"},
    new Animal {Color = "Green", Species = "Duck"},
    new Animal {Color = "White", Species = "Horse"},
    new Animal {Color = "Yellow", Species = "Dog", Breed = "Tasmania"}
    // etc.
};

var result = animals.Where(a => species.Contains(a.Species));
```

---

Note that the string search in the `HashSet` is case sensitive, if you do not want that you can supply a `StringComparer` as constructor argument:

`new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`